# Converting force layout from D3.js v3 to v5

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I'm trying to upgrade the working D3.js v3 collapsible graph code below to work under D3.js v5. I've changed layout.force() to use the new forceSimulation function as shown further below.

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    root;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(100)
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

//Added markers to indicate that this is a directed graph
svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["arrow"])
    .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 4)
    .attr("markerHeight", 4)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

d3.json("graph2.json", function(json) {
  root = json;
  //Give nodes ids and initialize variables
  for(var i=0; i<root.nodes.length; i++) {
    var node = root.nodes[i];
    node.id = i;
    node.collapsing = 0;
    node.collapsed = false;
  }
  //Give links ids and initialize variables
  for(var i=0; i<root.links.length; i++) {
    var link = root.links[i];
    link.source = root.nodes[link.source];
    link.target = root.nodes[link.target];
    link.id = i;
  }

  update();
});

function update() {
  //Keep only the visible nodes
  var nodes = root.nodes.filter(function(d) {
    return d.collapsing == 0;
  });
  var links = root.links;
  //Keep only the visible links
  links = root.links.filter(function(d) {
    return d.source.collapsing == 0 && d.target.collapsing == 0;
  });

  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

  // Update the links…
  link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Exit any old links.
  link.exit().remove();

  // Enter any new links.
  link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; })
      .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)");

  // Update the nodes…
  node = node.data(nodes, function(d){ return d.id; }).style("fill", color);

  // Exit any old nodes.
  node.exit().remove();

  // Enter any new nodes.
  node.enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; })
      .style("fill", color)
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);
}

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

// Color leaf nodes orange, and packages white or blue.
function color(d) {
  return d.collapsed ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (!d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
    //check if link is from this node, and if so, collapse
    root.links.forEach(function(l) {
      if(l.source.id == d.id) {
        if(d.collapsed){
          l.target.collapsing--;
        } else {
          l.target.collapsing++;
        }
      }
    });
    d.collapsed = !d.collapsed;
  }
  update();
}
```

I've changed the force block to:-

```
var force = d3.forceSimulation()
.force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
.force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
.force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.id)) 
.on("tick", tick);
```

but can't figure out what else needs to change. It doesn't draw anything.

Thanks.

Comment: At a glance, you'll also need to update d3.json as follows: `d3.json("graph2.json").then(function(json) {`

Comment: Did that but it doesn't help unfortunately.

Comment: It was only one thing that will need to be changed to use v5 (this was a change from v4 to v5) - I haven't had a chance to look for other issues.

Comment: I was converting code from v3 to v5. The code works under v3.

Comment: Yes, and you'll still need to change that (v4, v3 use the form `d3.json(file,function(error,data) {`, v5 uses `d3.json(file).then(function(data) {`. In updating from v3 you need to also account for changes made between v4 and v5. Though, there could be other parts that need updating too of course.

Comment: Yes, I understand, and I have made that change as I said above.

Comment: My apologies, I did not see that you had kept that change (I did see that you had tried it). Looking a bit closer I believe I see the other issue: `selection.enter()` in v3 automatically added the entered elements to `selection`. In d3v4+ selections are immutable and this doesn't happen. So `link` and `node` remain empty selections because when you define them, there are no links or nodes. In the tick function you could select all lines and nodes again (but this is time consuming every tick), or you could merge entered elements with existing ones: `link = link.enter().append(..)...merge(link)`

Comment: Well I've gor it drawing the graph now by using `force.force("link")` and `force.links(link)` but it is not updating correctly.  Each time I clck on a node it redraws without clearing the original.